# OpenGL code runs perfectly from IDE, CodeXL and GPU PerfStudio, but gives blank screen if started from Windows

Tags: c++, debugging, opengl, codeblocks

I have been improving an OpenGL code of my own since some days, and now I got a terrible surprise: My code works properly if run from inside CodeBlocks IDE (by Menu-> Build -> Run), but if I open it from the Windows Explorer, the program will still open and issue messages on the console as if it would be running properly, but I just get a blank screen.

I have trying re-building the code to see if the problem disappears from Windows, or to see if it also affects the run from inside CodeBlocks, but the outcome is still the same.

Some days ago (before much of the code change), I could start the program from both Windows and CodeBlocks and run perfectly in both cases, so this is totally surprising for me now.

I use GLFW3 and GLEW and I am linking to the following libraries:

- C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libglew32.dll.a
- C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libglfw3.a
- opengl32
- C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libsfml-system.dll.a (I use the clock of this library)
- gdi32

On the meantime I have deinstalled and installed msys64, but this didnt affect my other OpenGL projects linking the same libraries, so I suppose this is not the source of the problem

How would I proceed to debug such an issue? I have no clue about how to start troubleshooting this, so any comment on what extra info I should post is welcome.

**Update:** If I open the application from the GPU PerfStudio and CodeXL, everything works just fine, but not when I open via Windows Explorer.

Comment: Well, there are not too many options. Check everything again. Maybe you forgot to exit with a error if your program can't open some file? Codeblocks is well-known for setting weird working directory for projects. If it wont help, try to gradually reduce your example to hello world triangle until it starts to work. (Also, just saying, if you were using a version control system, this would be much easier.)

Comment: I always alter my code so that either it compiles and runs properly, or I undo all changes, and this has been satisfactory... until now :( Luckly, its a private thing, so no company will loose money for this, but it is still a good lesson!

Comment: I have a few questions, if I may: Do you use wgl functions (wglCreateContext, wglMakeCurrent, etc...) in your project? Have you enabled multisampling? Do you use shaders? Do you check for OpenGL errors?

Comment: No WGL, no texturing.

Your question about shaders has an interesting outcome: I check always for shader compile erros, and just as I test, I introduced temporarily a bug on the shader (to see if my program was correctly reading it), and my program thrown an exception because the shader didnt compile (I programmed the exception on purpose). But now, I change the name of the shader files to something that the program isnt supposed to recognize, and no error was throw. I also changed to shader content to introduce silly bugs againt and suddently no error is thrown!

Comment: Sorry for the last confusing comment. Here is the update:

No WGL, no multisampling. I check for shader compile errors, even though I dont check if the shader file is found or not. But I know that the file is being found because if I introduce an artificial bug on the shader code, my program throws an exception as expected saying that the shader didnt compile properly (checked via glGetShaderiv(_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status). If status is not 1, an exception is thrown.

Comment: Maybe you have an issue with linking, can you try building the same project with visual studio ?

Comment: Thanks for answers. Just to be clear: I meant [MSAA](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Multisampling), not texture multisampling. Windows does not like it (you need to create dummy OpenGL context etc..) . I only asked that question because I ran into similar issue when programming it.
Since now I know you use GLEW I have a new, better question: do you check if glewInit() returns GLEW_OK?

Comment: I didnt put anything in my code about multisampling, so I supposed its turned of. My glewInit() returns GLEW_OK, so no problem there.

Comment: @Yvain: I deleted the linked libraries from CodeBlocks and added again, and the same error (only when started outside the IDE) persists, so I dont assume its a linker error. As downloading VS and learning how to use it will take time, I will do it after I`ve exhausted all other quicker options. Thanks!

Comment: I have downloaded an OpenGL debugger (AMD GPU PerfStudio) and it worked fine too!

Answer (score 1):

> How would I proceed to debug such an issue?

When I deal with bugs like this I use a tool called [CodeXL](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/codexl/). You can download the latest version [here](https://github.com/GPUOpen-Tools/CodeXL/releases/tag/v2.2). It automatically breaks on any OpenGL error and shows you which of your OpenGL function calls caused it.

It is free and it works also with non-AMD GPUs.

It should not take you long time to learn how to use it: you just create a new project, give it path to your project folder and .exe and hit run. (make sure that Debug->Breakpoints->Break on OpenGL error is checked)

//Moreover, it visualizes your buffers, shows you your loaded textures, etc.. Definitely check it if you plan to program more Windows+OpenGL in the future.

Comment: My program also worked perfectly under CodeXL and GPU PerfStudio, but when opening from the Windows Explorer I got a blank screen again. That is so weird!

Comment: When you run the .exe from Windows Explorer, are the shader files next to it (in the same folder)?

Comment: Yes they are, but not the libraries. I dont think the libraries being there or in other directory would make any difference?

Comment: Well, static libraries (.lib) are used during linking and if you are missing some required dynamic library (.dll), the .exe would not even start. So no, they should not make any difference.